# Return vs. Goexit for goroutines

Tags: go

I did some digging, but didn't really find anything satisfactory, so I'm asking: are their any best practices or pros/cons for using return vs. runtime.Goexit for exiting a goroutine?  So far, the only thing I came across in some testing is that if you're using waitgroups, it may not call the Done function.

Specific to the waitgroups (if interested): in some quick testing in a codebase I have, I create an anonymous function that executes as a goroutine to test a method that's supposed to run within a goroutine.  I tried to use defer to have it call wg.Done() when the function called runtime.Goexit, but it didn't work.  Not sure if this is intended or a bug.

Code example:

```
go func() {
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()
    // Function goes here...
}()
```

Answer (score 11):

You should rarely ever need to use `runtime.Goexit`. It's used to terminate the current goroutine, when you *can't* return from the call site, e.g. when you are in a function call within the goroutine. In the std library, the testing package uses it in functions like `FailNow` and `SkipNow` to immediately end the current test. In general, you should return normally from your goroutines to keep the code clear, and prevent unexpected behavior.

The problem in your example is that you need to call `wg.Add` *before* you start the goroutine, otherwise you could reach the `Wait` call before the `wg.Add` calls have been executed.

```
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    // Function goes here...
}()
```

Comment: The waitgroup was just an example, though I do appreciate the answer.  I'm more interested in is pros/cons or best practices of using each.

Comment: @blockcipher: added note about a use for Goexit.

Comment: There really aren't many uses for it--it seems like essentially a `panic()` that can't be `recover()`ed from. The most likely scenario I can see is when you've exposed an API that means something like "exit", as `FailNow()` does.